# Profiling Traces of Instructions on RISCV using GEM5

Tags: profiling, riscv, gem5

I am using gem5 with RISCV cross compiler and I was able to run my RISCV executable with the example configuration file se.py.
I want to profile the executable for every phase of instructions and find the time it takes to execute them, is this possible to do with gem5?
There are a lot of profilers to do so with x86, but I am not sure if there are any with RISCV.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/debugging_and_testing/debugging/trace_based_debugging) documentation from the official gem5 page. You can see that by using the `--debug-flags=ExecAll` option with the .opt and .debug variations of gem5, you can create detailed instruction traces for your simulated program for all stages of the pipeline.

To get a list of all available flags just run `build/RISCV/gem.opt --debug-help`.

You can combine different flags and redirect the trace output to any file using `--debug-file`.

ExecAll is very detailed and can be tiresome to go through so I would suggest using individual simple flags that are a part of the ExecAll compound flag.

You can see the simple v/s compound flags when you do `--debug-help`.

Hope this solves your issue.